# Combining two LinearLayouts in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So essentially I am trying to combine two linearlayouts in xml for android. My problem is that when I combine the second xml file by putting this in the first using :

```
  <include
        android:id="@+id/name_goes_here"
        layout="@layout/name_goes_here" />
```

it blows out of proportion and covers over the first. Essentially in the highlighted portion below that has the controls xml I am trying to put my buttons xml file in place of that instead. However, my error is that when I edit the

**My first xml (activity_main.xml) looks like this:**

[image: First xml]

Right now the xml file looks like this: (the bottom half that is highlighted in a separate xml file called controls.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"

              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="520dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
            android:id="@+id/seekArc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="30dp"
            seekarc:rotation="180"
            seekarc:startAngle="0"
            seekarc:sweepAngle="360"
            seekarc:touchInside="true"
            seekarc:arcColor="#ff5ac3ff"
            seekarc:progressColor="#ffff3a35"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seekArcProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </FrameLayout>



    <include
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        layout="@layout/controls" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to put this in place of controls. This is buttons.xml

[image]

Not sure how to implement the change in this case because the include tag results in the xml files being over each other

**This is the buttons.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/block_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/block_apps"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/security_settings_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/security_settings"

        android:textSize="22sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/blacklist_whitelist_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff5ac3ff"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_blacklist_red"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/blacklist_whitelist"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read this (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<merge>` tag. See details here (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).